# How can I select list of items in listview within my code ( not by user)

Tags: android, listview

How can I 'check' list of items in listview within my code ( not by user)

```
ProcessList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,nameList ));
ProcessList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

for example like ProcessList.(check these items...)
Just like we get items 'checked' by user from: ProcessList.getItemAtPosition(position);

Pls also suggest me anyother way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`setItemChecked()`](http://goo.gl/sN7Lx) on the `ListView` for each position to be checked.

Also, please grow up. Badgering people on Twitter minutes after you post a question on StackOverflow is infantile. This is a volunteer resource -- if you require answers to questions in under an hour, hire a consultant.

Comment: I apologise and Thank you very much for helping me